# AVR PWM configuration

Tags: microcontroller, avr, codevisionavr

I know this is silly but I got really confused.

I want to make a PWM pulse with 3 modes on Atmega16:
1- 1Khz with Duty cycle 100%
2- 4Khz with Duty cycle 100%
3- 1Khz with Duty cycle 50%

I was away from AVR for almost 2 years and I forgot everything, so I just need the calculations of Timer 1 in a simple way.
any thing I have read makes me more confused. Is there something that could help me?
I'm using Codevision AVR.

Comment: You'll have better luck at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. This is probably off-topic here because you're not talking about code at all but the hardware timers on the AVR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, but I got exams so it got too long to post it.
I set the Fcpu to 4MHz

and here is the code:

```
void set1KhzDC100()
{
// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: 500.000 kHz
// Mode: Fast PWM top=0x01FF
// OC1A output: Non-Inv.
// OC1B output: Discon.
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: Off
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off
TCCR1A=0x82;
TCCR1B=0x0A;
TCNT1H=0;
TCNT1L=0;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;
OCR1A=511;
}

void Set4KhzDC100()
{
// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: 4000.000 kHz
// Mode: Fast PWM top=0x03FF
// OC1A output: Non-Inv.
// OC1B output: Discon.
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: Off
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off
TCCR1A=0x83;
TCCR1B=0x09;
TCNT1H=0x00;
TCNT1L=0x00;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;
OCR1A=1023;
OCR1BH=0x00;
OCR1BL=0x00;
}

void Set1KhzDC50()
{
// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: 500.000 kHz
// Mode: Fast PWM top=0x01FF
// OC1A output: Non-Inv.
// OC1B output: Discon.
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: Off
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off
TCCR1A=0x82;
TCCR1B=0x0A;
TCNT1H=0;
TCNT1L=0;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;
OCR1A=255;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1- 1Khz with Duty cycle 100%

2- 4Khz with Duty cycle 100%

are the same thing. There is no actual PWM at all. The output is high all the time and frequency doesn't matter.

3- 1Khz with Duty cycle 50%

is actually PWM. There are a few types to choose from, but if the duty cycle is going to be exactly 50%, then there are easy ways to achieve this with a toggle. From the manual,

> A frequency (with 50% duty cycle) waveform output in fast PWM mode can be achieved by setting OC1A to toggle its logical level on each compare match (COM1A1:0 = 1). This applies only if OCR1A is used to define the TOP value (WGM13:0 = 15).

That is, set the COM1A1 and COM1A0 bits of TCCR1A to be `01`, and set all the WGM bits of TCCR1A and TCCR1B to be `1`. Choose OCR1A and the CSx prescalar bits of TCCR1B so that OCR1A is reached every 0.5 ms.